# Remove old items and loading new ones from listbox on pressing button

Tags: asp.net

I am stuck with a simple problem but not able to figure out the solution
I have an asp.net application that queries some data from data reader based on filters and updates in a listbox when Done button is pressed. The problem is that if i modify the selection and press Done again, the old values are still present i.e. I get old results and the new ones are appended. How do remove the old values so that everytime I modify my selection I get only the new values.

Comment: Don't rebind the ListBox on postbacks in Page_Load: `if(!PostBack)BindListBox();`

Comment: No, he needs to bind it, he just needs to get rid of what's already there (which is saved in the ViewState, I think).

Comment: No, if he binds it in Page_Load then rebinding it there will erase any user changes.  Unless he binds it in Page_Init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you're loading the values in Page_Load, be sure to surround your loading code with an `if(!Page.IsPostback)` statement to ensure you're not re-binding it on every load.  (See the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for details.)

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
   // Binding code goes here.
}
```

(Alternatively, you can bind it on every page load in Page_Init instead of Page_Load, which will allow you to bind it and have the user-entries be applied when the Viewstate is applied.  Again, see the Page Lifecycle for details.  Or [this great article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx).)

Next, ensure that you are calling the Clear() command on the listbox to remove items.

> MyListBox.Items.Clear()